# tiva c implicit function

Tags: c, texas-instruments

I am trying to build a simple logic analyzer with TM4c123 but anytime when I use the function ROM_.... it appears to be an error( implicit of function ROM_..) Anyone knows why?

for example:

```
ROM_FPUEnable();
ROM_FPULazyStackingEnable();

// run from crystal, 80 MHz
ROM_SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_2_5 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);

// enable peripherals
ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);

// set UART pins
GPIOPinConfigure(0x00000001);
GPIOPinConfigure(0x00000401);
ROM_GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);

// init PORTB
ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOB);
GPIO_PORTB_DIR_R = 0x00;
GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R = 0xff;

// configure uart
ROM_UARTConfigSetExpClk(UART0_BASE, ROM_SysCtlClockGet(), 115200,
    (UART_CONFIG_WLEN_8 | UART_CONFIG_STOP_ONE | UART_CONFIG_PAR_NONE));
```

All of the function ROM are errors, why? I already include rom.h and rom_map.h

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your tiva microcontroller has some functions inside it already. Then they are stored in some part of memory. If I'm not mistaken there must be a file provided bytexas instruments that indicates where in memory they are stored. If your program is giving you that error maybe you're not including the correct file

Comment: Rather than describe "I already include rom.h and rom_map.h", post the code that does that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't defined your target device.
Try to add something like `-DTARGET_IS_TM4C123_RB1` to your Makefile.
This define is necessary in order for the ROM_* symbols be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a combination of driverlib (tivaware) and direct register modification (DRM). Use one or the other, preferably driverlib.

You should actually be using the MAP_ calls instead of ROM_. ROM_ is deprecated but still usable for testing. Don't put ROM_ in production code. I know the examples still use ROM_.

You are missing the header file for ROM anyways. If you want to use ROM_, you need to include driverlib/rom.h. That's why it's complaining about the implicit function call. Any call to a ROM_somethingsomethingdarkside() is not defined. You will also need to include stdint and stdbool, as driverlib uses those c99 types. To use the map calls, you'll need to include driverlib/rom_map.h

You may also need to include driverlib/gpio.h, driverlib/sysctrl.h. Not sure on that. I've never mixed things like you have done, and I always debug using the compiled in driverlib first, then prefixed the driverlib calls with MAP_ after I know things are working. I haven't ever gone back to remove my includes for the compiled in driverlib libraries. The toolchain seems to be smart enough to not compile them in after I stop calling them anyways. Now I kinda want to try that though.

To be clear, ROM_ or MAP_ is calling driverlib calls out of the on chip ROM.

I suspect that you are not sure what the code you are using really is and what it does by the way you're mixing DRM and driverlib libraries. I HIGHLY suggest you take the time to go through the online workshop for the Tiva C. It's a series of short videos and labs that will clear up all of this. I went intentionally neurotically slow and it took me a weekend. You can do it in a day, and it'll be a day well spent. It'll save you that many times over. It's out of date slightly as far as code composer goes, but it's still useable. I have all my students go through it before they start work on this platform.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_TIVA™_C_Series_TM4C123G_LaunchPad

Edit: yes, and as vitor points out, you also need that define as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend using "driverlib/gpio.h" and "driverlib/sysctl.h"
for the Pin configuration with TM4C devices